# Is it possible to display HTML content in a smarty variable, that is escaped using escape:HTML?

Tags: php, escaping, smarty

I have a smarty variable in *.tpl that cannot be changed:

```
{$some_value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
```

I have to assign a new value for this variable in PHP. This new value contains some basic HTML:

```
$some_value = '<span>'.$val.'</span>';
```

Is it possible to get is parsed as HTML somehow?

*I know that it is definitely better to include all HTML tags in tpl and not in PHP, but in this particular case tpl cannot be edited.*

Answer (score 1):

No. The entire point of escaping for HTML in the template is to make that impossible.